# Selenium and iframe

Tags: iframe, selenium

I have an iframe that gets loaded when i click on a tab on a page. When i use Firebug to look at the iframe on IE8, all i see is:

`iframe id=tabContextFrame class=contextFrame contentEditable=inherit src=/xyz.dt?forward=show&layouttype=NoHeader&runid=1234  name=tabContextFrame url=/xyz.dt?forward=show&layouttype=NoHeader&runid=1234  scrolling=auto`

and that's it.The hierarchy below the iframe can't be seen. I want to click on a link within the iframe. To find the elements within the iframe, I did a `selenium.click("on the tab that loads the iframe")` and then `selenium.getHtmlSource()`. From this source, I can at least locate my link of interest. I did a `selenium.click("//span[text()='Link']")` but it doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas please?

Here is the code:

```
selenium.click("//span[text()='tab that loads iframe']");   
Thread.sleep(5000);   
selenium.selectFrame("tabContextFrame");         
selenium.mouseOver("//span[text()='Link']");   
selenium.mouseDown("//span[text()='Link']");  
selenium.mouseUp("//span[text()='Link']");   
Thread.sleep(5000);   
selenium.selectFrame("null");
```

Comment: Did u try selenium 2.0 with web driver? U can use driver.SwitchTo().Frame()

Comment: possible duplicate of [handling iframe in webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/handling-iframe-in-webdriver)

Answer (score 40):

I'm guessing you are using Selenium 1.0.  Have you looked at Selenium 2.0 and WebDriver.  I found the following and it worked for me:

> Q: How do I type into a contentEditable iframe? A: Assuming that the
>   iframe is named "foo":
>
> ```
> driver.switchTo().frame("foo");
> WebElement editable = driver.switchTo().activeElement(); 
> editable.sendKeys("Your text here");
> ```
>
> Sometimes this doesn't work, and this is because the iframe
>   doesn't have any content. On Firefox you can execute the following
>   before "sendKeys":
>
> ```
> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.body.innerHTML = '<br>'");
> ```
>
> This is needed because the iframe has no content by default:
>   there's nothing to send keyboard input to. This method call inserts an
>   empty tag, which sets everything up nicely.
>
> Remember to switch out of the frame once you're done (as all further
>   interactions will be with this specific frame):
>
> ```
> driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
> ```

I found this on http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Answer (score 0):

Use driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); first then do your operation