# How to handle iframe in Selenium WebDriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

```html
<div>    
  <iframe id="cq-cf-frame ">    
    <iframe id="gen367">   
      <body spellcheck="false" id="CQrte" style="height: 255px; font-size: 12px; font-family:tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; background-image: url(&quot;/libs/cq/ui/widgets/themes/default/ext/form/text-bg.gif&quot;); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-attachment: fixed;">
        <p>4t43t4<br></p>
      </body >
    </iframe>
  </iframe>    
</div>
```

In this scenario there is an `iframe` under `iframe`. And I have to select the outer `iframe` to go to inner `iframe` and write in the body which is in the inner `iframe`.

Next, I have to come out from the inner `iframe` to outer `iframe` and click on OK button, (which is in the outer `iframe`).

**Following is my code**

```java
/*Line 1 */ driver.switchTo().frame("cq-cf-frame");
/*     2 */ driver.findElement(By.css("#extdd-9 > div.tblRow >  input.edititem").click();
/*     3 */ driver.switchTo().Frame("cq-gen379");
/*     4 */ driver.findElement(By.id("CQrte").sendKeys("Tnx");  
/*     5 */ selenium.selectFrame("relative=up");       
/*     6 */ driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']")).click();
```

**Following is my problem:**

My test code is working fine up to line number 4 i.e. writing into the body, but I want to come out from inner to outer `iframe` it says that the element `//button[text()='OK']` not found.

I tried with using index, parent, relative, but had no luck.

**NOTE:** If I don’t select the inner frame (`cq-gen379`). I'm able to click on the OK button.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In Webdriver, you should use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` to get out of a frame.
You need to get out of all the frames first, then switch into outer frame again.

```java
// between step 4 and step 5
// remove selenium.selectFrame("relative=up");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // you are now outside both frames
driver.switchTo().frame("cq-cf-frame");
// now continue step 6
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']")).click();
```

Comment: Also, as an FYI: I have found that switchTo().frame need implicit wait disactivated:  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 43):

You have to get back out of the Iframe with the following code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
//do your stuff
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: I agree on this answer.  In the "//do your stuff" section I would use a JavaScriptExectutor if the DOM returned happens to appear to be null.  Q:  Why is the method call ".frame" when the actual tag name is "iframe" ???  Aren't frames/framesets different than a iframe?

Comment: Hi this is just my guess but an iframe is still some sort of frame and this piece of code isn't iframe exclusive so it should worke with other frames (I did not check that)

Comment: If you save the url with `driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(data) {
 console.log("the url is : "+data);
});` you will find it is a different path without some of the features. You have basically left behind all of your scripts. I am still trying to figure this out myself.

Answer (score 23):

You need to first find `iframe`. You can do so using following statement.

```
WebElement iFrame= driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
```

Then, you can swith to it using `switchTo` method on you `WebDriver` object.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
```

And to move back to the parent frame, you can either use `switchTo().parentFrame()` or if you want to get back to the main (or most parent) frame, you can use `switchTo().defaultContent();`.

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();    // to move back to parent frame
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // to move back to most parent or main frame
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

To get back to the parent frame, use:

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

To get back to the first/main frame, use:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-examples");
Thread.sleep(3000);
//Switch to nested frame
driver.switchTo().frame("aswift_2").switchTo().frame("google_ads_frame3");
```

Answer (score 3):

Below approach of frame handling : When no id or name is given incase of nested frame

```
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block-block19']//iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(element);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='carousel']/li/div/div[3]/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Selenium Web Driver Handling Frames**

 It is impossible to click [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) directly through XPath since it is an iframe. *First we have to switch to the frame and then we can click using xpath.*

`driver.switchTo().frame()` has multiple overloads.

1. `driver.switchTo().frame(name_or_id)`

   Here your `iframe` doesn't have id or name, so not for you.
2. `driver.switchTo().frame(index)`

   This is the last option to choose, because using index is not stable enough as you could imagine. If this is your only iframe in the page, try `driver.switchTo().frame(0)`
3. `driver.switchTo().frame(iframe_element)`

   The most common one. You locate your iframe like other elements, then pass it into the method.

`driver.switchTo().`[defaultContent](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.45.0/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java#WebDriver.TargetLocator)`(); [parentFrame, defaultContent, frame]`

```java
// Based on index position:
int frameIndex = 0;
List<WebElement> listFrames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println("list frames   "+listFrames.size());
driver.switchTo().frame(listFrames.get( frameIndex ));

// XPath|CssPath Element:
WebElement frameCSSPath = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='Fill Quote']"));
WebElement frameXPath = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[1]"));
WebElement frameTag = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

driver.switchTo().frame( frameCSSPath ); // frameXPath, frameTag


driver.switchTo().frame("relative=up"); // focus to parent frame.
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // move to the most parent or main frame

// For alert's
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); // Switch to alert pop-up
alert.accept();
alert.dismiss();
```

XML Test:

```java
<html>
    <IFame id='1'>...       parentFrame() « context remains unchanged. <IFame1>
    |
     -> <IFrame id='2'>...  parentFrame() « Change focus to the parent context. <IFame1>
</html>

</html>
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
    <Fame id='11'>...     defaultContent() « driver focus to top window/first frame. <html>
    |
     -> <Frame id='22'>... defaultContent() « driver focus to top window/first frame. <Fame11> 
                           frame("relative=up") « focus to parent frame. <Fame11>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Conversion of RC to Web-Driver Java commands. [link](https://www.noblis-nsp.com/convert-selenium-1-remotecontrol-to-selenium-2-webdriver/).

---

[`<frame>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame) is an HTML element which defines a particular area in which another HTML document can be displayed. A frame should be used within a `<frameset>`. « *[Deprecated](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/144516/195891)*. Not for use in new websites.