# Selenium Webdriver FIle Upload error element ice:inputFile

Tags: file, selenium, upload, webdriver

this is my first post and sorry for asking the same question once again. I am stuck with a issue regarding uploading a file in Selenium Web Driver. I have searched a lot in this forum but the solutions are not working for me.  The element which is the file Browse button is embedded in the file text area ( i.e. where the path of the file gets printed after the browsing through file browse dialog box), but the upload button is separate.

The entire element code is:

`<input class="iceInpFileTxt" type="file" size="35" name="upload">`

I am unable to click on the "browse" button using click() method. I have tried using Autoit/Robot also.

The code of the element from JSP page:
`<ice:inputFile id="fileUpload" width="600" autoUpload="true"
                                                                                            value="#{practitionerLoadDataBean.inputFile}"
                                                                                            actionListener="#{practitionerLoadControllerBean.browse}"/>`

I know the input type is file so sendkeys() should work. The codes I have been trying are:

`WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='upload']"));
elem.sendKeys("<PATH>");`

The error message shows as:
`org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException:Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='upload']"}`

Please let me know where I my mistake is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element was simply invisible, it would have been found, but you wouldn't be able to interact with it. The usual solution is to look around for frames.

[You can't search for elements contained in frames, you have to switch your driver's context to that frame first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/handling-iframe-in-webdriver)

[`driver.switchTo().frame("frameName");`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html)

Then you'll be able to find the element and upload the file the usual way (please, use the `sendKeys()` method describes by other answers in here).

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that the input element is visible

Do not click on the browse button, it will open an system level dialogue box to upload the file & Its very tedious to handle this in selenium.

you can use the following method:

driver.find_element(:id,'videoupload').send_keys("E:\\video.flv")

Please check the "\\" in your code.

Please Keep in mind that the upload will work only If the element you send a file should be in the form

Hope this will work for you.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ Sidram Waghmare.This is the entire form of the page:
<form id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/hip-webapp/uploadHtml" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="batchLoad:inputFile" name="ice.component">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="ice.view">
<input class="iceInpFileTxt" type="file" size="35" name="upload">
<input class="iceInpFileBtn" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>. Can you confirm if the element is hidden? If yes, Is there any workaround to automate this? TIA.

Comment: Hi avishek, Yes your input element is hidden because in your code it is clearly showing that **input type="hidden"**. Above code will work only if your input element is visible & should NOT be hidden. One kindly suggestion that from next time please paste your code in the script. that will be very useful for us to more understanding.. :)

Comment: Thanks @Sidram, by the way is there any workaround to automate this? Please mention if you can give any pointer as I am stuck with the automation for this file uploading part. I talked to a developer who said the properties of an element are not set by them, its the framework which they are using sets it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

File Upload Using SendKeys

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("URl");

File file=null;

try
{
file=new File("file path");
}

catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

Assert.assertTrue(file.exists());

WebElement browserButton=driver.findElement(By.id("button Id"));

browserButton.sendkeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the can you check the element tags I have uploaded and check if that will work for your code. What I thought is your code is idiot proofing and more correct than what I have shared. But the purpose is the same and works the same as well. But I am unable to locate the element itself. I would appreciate if you can give some more detailed input on this. TIL.

Comment: As you can see <input class="iceInpFileTxt" type="file" size="35" name="upload"> ,Input type is file so CLICK WILL NOT WORK..

Comment: I modified the code as below:File file=null;

  try
  {
  file=new File("D:\\AD\\Prac\\Prac\\002 EditPrac Add Person Error.xml-revHEAD.svn000.tmp.xml");
  }

  catch(Exception e)
  {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

  Assert.assertTrue(file.exists());

  WebElement browserButton=driver.findElement(By.className("iceInpFileTxt"));

  browserButton.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath()); - still it gives the same error-element not found. I tried using xpath as well but that did not work either. Please advice,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
```