# Need help for webdriver and Javascript for a hidden File upload element

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate a file upload scenario in a client web application. The code of the entire file upload form looks like this

```
<td valign="top">
    <iframe id="batchLoad:inputFile:uploadFrame" class="iceInpFile" width="600px" scrolling="no" height="30px"             frameborder="0" title="Input File Frame" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0px; padding:0px;" src="/hip-webapp/block/resource/LTExMzg4MjQzMTY=/" name="batchLoad:inputFile:uploadFrame" marginwidth="0"       marginheight="0" allowtransparency="true">
        <html style="overflow:hidden;">
            <head>
                <body style="background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden">
                    <form id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/hip-webap/uploadHtml" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" value="batchLoad:inputFile" name="ice.component">
                        <input type="hidden" value="3" name="ice.view">
                        <input class="iceInpFileTxt" type="file" size="35" name="upload">
                        <input class="iceInpFileBtn" type="submit" value="Upload">
                    </form>
                </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
    <br>
    <span id="batchLoad:j_id537"></span>
</td>
```

I tried with the conventional File upload method, but that did not work.

Please refer: [Selenium Webdriver FIle Upload error element ice:inputFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668826/selenium-webdriver-file-upload-error-element-iceinputfile)

I am not much familiar with Javascript hence I think I am doing some syntax error.
What I tried is:

```
String ew = (String)js.executeScript("document.getElementByXPath('//form[@id='fileUploadForm']/input[3]')");
String j = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
js.executeScript(j, ew);
```

Got the hint from here [Selenium WebDriver clicking on hidden element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040615/selenium-webdriver-clicking-on-hidden-element).

But now I am getting syntax error. I got the XPath using Selenium IDE. I have also tried this, but that did not work either.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementByClassName(iceInpFileTxt).style.visibility = 'visible';");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementByClassName('iceInpFileTxt').value = 'D:\\AD\\Prac\\Prac\\002 EditPrac Add Person Error.xml-revHEAD.svn000.tmp.xml'");
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is an `<iframe>` element on the page you're working with, you need to [switch the `driver` context to that `<iframe>` element first](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame%28org.openqa.selenium.WebElement%29):

```
driver.switchTo().frame("batchLoad:inputFile:uploadFrame");
```

Once you've done that, try the usual upload method again.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("upload")).sendKeys("D:\\AD\\Prac\\Prac\\002 EditPrac Add Person Error.xml-revHEAD.svn000.tmp.xml");
```

Note that when you'll try to interact with elements outside the `<iframe>`, you'll have to do `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` beforehand.

---

Side notes:

- The `iframe` does not have a closing `</head>` tag. This is not an issue, but something you might think about since you're most likely developing the web :).
- You certainly don't have to make the invisible elements visible nor should you inject the file to the hidden input element manually unless for some Flash/Silverlight controls. You could have simply set the `value` right away.
- `String ew = (String)js.executeScript("document.getElementByXPath('//form[@id='fileUploadForm']/input[3]')");`

  contains an error. You are using nested `'` which does not work. You should escape the inner single quote via a `\`. Also, it should return a `WebElement`, so you should cast the result to `WebElement`, not to a `String`.
- `js.executeScript(j, ew);`

  As said above, the second argument should be a `WebElement`. Also, if you had switched to the correct frame before, you could have found it the usual way via `driver.findElement()`.
- `document.getElementByClassName()` does not exist. The right method name is `document.getElementsByClassName()` (note the plural "elements"). And it returns a set of elements, so you need to iterate over them in a for loop, or blindly pick the first one (`[0]`).
- `document.getElementByClassName(iceInpFileTxt).style.visibility = 'visible';`

  contains an error, the method (if it existed) takes a string, so you should quote the `"iceInpFileTxt"`.

Comment: Switching to frame helped, thanks a lot! Now I don't need javascript to unhide the element..But still thanks for the side notes as well!