# many buttons with the same id

Tags: selenium, liferay, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to test a page with multiple portlets made by liferay.

Every portlet is having a save button with the same id, it use the iframe id of the portlet to differentiate between the buttons.

How can I write a code in selenium that can understand which button I mean??

Comment: Does each buttons have same name too?

Comment: Can u please share the html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `driver.switchTo().frame(IFrameElement)`.  Any kind of IFrame you need to switch in/out of.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943605/1769273

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath or css selectors to find children dependent on parents.

paste your html and we can provide examples

Answer (score 0):

Does this mean your portlets are all embedding iframes? Typically portlets just render HTML snippets into the same documents. In this case, your implementation would be considered flawed: Portlets must not use IDs that can conflict. E.g. you should not render

```
 <input type="submit" id="save"/>
```

but

```
 <input type="submit" id="<portlet:namespace/>save"/>
```

or similar - make sure the id is unique, as it ends up in the same HTML-DOM which - by specification - assumes ids are unique.

There are other methods to create unique ids, but keep in mind: If you come up with the prefix yourself, per portlet, someone might add the same portlet to the page twice and you can end up with the same id even though all *different* portlets have unique ids.

If you are indeed rendering many different iframes from your portlets, you can disregard this answer or take it as a suggestion to make better use of the portal environment by changing the implementation.