# Unable to identify the element inside another html

Tags: java, html, selenium

I've got a page like below and I 'm trying to identify the element `DivToFind` using **selenium**. But, as they are inside a frame and then inside another `html`, i'm unable to find it.

I 've tried below.

`SwitchTo().frame()` - Did not work
Window handler swapping - there is only one window handler

Any suggestions please?

```
<html>
<head>
<body unselectable="off">
<div ..... >
<iframe src="/something.jsp" name="FrameBox">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="DivToFind">
........

</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
</iframe>

</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: The frame switching happend successfully but then, the code is unable to identify the 'DivToFind' element. Any thoughts please?

`driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'FrameBox')]")));
System.out.println("switched");
driver.findElement(By.id("DivToFind"));
System.out.println("Found");`

Comment: One more point. Even though switchTo().frame() is successful, as there is another <html> starts, the code is unable to identify the elements inside.

Comment: hi Rupesh,

So, I gave below lines and it went through successfully ('found' was printed). I got some error using assertTrue and thus didn't use that.

         driver.getPageSource().contains("DivToFind");
         System.out.println("Found");

   
But, when I use inspect element in firefox, I don't see anything inside. It is like this.

<iframe name="FrameBox">
                    #document
                        <html webdriver="true">
                            <head></head>
                            <body></body>
                        </html>
                </iframe>

Comment: In this case Just seeing HTML will not work. The element which you are try to locate where it is present in i.e like alert, Window,etc. Can you show complete implementation in that case. Or will be more easy if the site you are trying to automate is publicly available.

Comment: hope fully this should answer your question 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9960432/1520443

Comment: Hi Rupesh, the code in the actual post is the same html code that im trying to automate.. Just a html created in my local drive.

Comment: Hi Deepak, that did not work. Still unable to identify the element