# Unable to find element with xpath due to different division

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Could you help to fix this error. Received error as:

> Unable to find element with xpath

Below the tags for the element which is a Text area

```
<td nowrap="">
<script> 
function clipBrdAction(evt, fieldName) { 
    evt = evt||window.event;     
    if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode==67) {      
        document.execCommand('copy');      
        //var temp = $(fieldName).value;      
        //clipboardData.setData('Text', temp);      
        //$(fieldName).value = clipboardData.getData('Text');     
    }     
    else if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode==86) {
        document.execCommand('paste');      
        //$(fieldName).value = clipboardData.getData('Text');     
    }     
    else if(evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode==88) {      
        document.execCommand('cut');      
        //var temp = $(fieldName).value;      
        //clipboardData.setData('Text', temp);      
        //$(fieldName).value = '';     
    } else if(evt.keyCode==46) {      
        document.execCommand('delete');      
        //var selStart = $(fieldName).selectionStart;      
        //var selEnd = $(fieldName).selectionEnd;      
        //var fieldLen = $(fieldName).value.length;      
        //if (selEnd == fieldLen)         
        // temp = $(fieldName).value.substr(0,selStart);      
    //else if (selEnd > selStart)      
        // temp = $(fieldName).value.substr(0,selStart)+ $(fieldName).value.substr(selEnd, fieldLen);     
    //else      
        // temp = $(fieldName).value.substr(0,selStart)+ $(fieldName).value.substr((+selEnd + +1), fieldLen);      

    //clipboardData.setData('Text', temp);      
    //$(fieldName).value = clipboardData.getData('Text');     
} 
</script>

<textarea id="nrpsFilter" rows="3" onkeypress="return checkIt(event,'');" cols="30" title="" onblur="this.value=trim(this.value);" onkeyup="" onkeydown="return clipBrdAction(event, 'nrpsFilter');" name="nrpsFilter"/>
</td>
```

And my code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nrpsFilter']")).sendKeys("*1??0*");
```

In Firepath, the element is identifiable, after when i search for another element that is under same division (div tag) but not identifiable after searching for an element from different division. Does that mean I should Switch to the division in my code? Both the divisions are under same Frame.

Comment: post your html source code as well

Comment: Sorry, Im not allowed to share the source code.

Comment: ok is that textarea  inside the iframe please  confirm

Comment: Yes Raj. The text area is inside the iframe.

Comment: Please post the code you are using and any relevant info that is missing from the question. Mentioning info in the comments is fine but you need to put that info in the question itself so others can more easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then just before using Sendkeys please switch to the iframe first after that your code will work without any problem.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame name");
// perform your action 
// after you have performed all your action inside the iframe 
// plz switch back to the default content 

driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
// now perform your user action outside that iframe
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: also plz have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-webdriver

Comment: Thanks Raj. I added the switchTo() function and now the code looks like this:

Comment: 'driver.switchTo().frame("bodyframe");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='first']//span")).click(); //(1. Click Dropdown')
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-33']/span")).click(); //(2. Click SubDropDown )
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Quick Search')][@id='referential_quicksearch']")).click(); //(3.Click the link)
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    //driver.switchTo().frame("bodyframe");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nrpsFilter']")).sendKeys("1?0*");//(Enter in textArea)'

Comment: did it worked ? Also why are you switching to same frame two times ? Switching just before sendkeys will also work

Comment: No Raj it didnt work. Yes, i need to change from BANNER to the frame(bodyframe), so need to switch initially(Doesn't work without this statement). Could you advise if Im missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works. I took it from your comment but rearranged a couple statements. I think you want the final `sendkeys()` to be in the `IFRAME` also, right? We really need more complete HTML to help any further.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='first']//span")).click(); // (1. Click Dropdown)
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-33']/span")).click(); // (2. Click SubDropDown )
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Quick Search')][@id='referential_quicksearch']")).click(); // (3.Click the link)
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nrpsFilter']")).sendKeys("1?0*");// (Enter in textArea)
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```