# xpath string works on chrome but not in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I use xpath of Chrome extension to get element's xpath.

```
span[@id='txt_btn_continue']
```

It works on the browser but not in code.The error i get is

```
Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='txt_btn_continue']"}
```

I cannot figure out the reason. Anyone could help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have noticed that the two xpaths are not the same (span vs. *)?

Comment: Without further infos, nobody can answer this. The selector looks valid.

Comment: can you share some html code or the whole website? What error you get?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht the ``*`` covers the ``span``, so that's not an issue.

Comment: @f1sh Well, without further info, it *could* be an issue and should at least be clarified.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht since ``*`` is less specific than ``span``, the xpath could find _more_ elements, but none are found.

Comment: This could be [timing issue](http://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html) or [element could be located inside an `iframe`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-webdriver). Check both options

Comment: @f1sh from a technical POV I totally agree and never said that * won't work. But as the two selectors differ, maybe the OP has a problem somewhere else (wrong code branch)? They should just clarify, that's all.

Comment: If you have the id of and element why don't to try using ID itself ?

Comment: answer of such question has already been answered couple of time in this forum, please search them before posting it.

Comment: @RogersShu Your question is unclear/invalid `use xpath of Chrome extension to get element's xpath`. Can you rephrase your Question with the exact requirement please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential reasons:**

- your element is in a frame and you need to switch to it before
  search.
- element is hidden or disabled and in the code you need to
  perform exactly the same steps before selecting element which you do
  manually (in the test)
- the page is not fully loaded at the moment
  you search for the element.