# How to handle this nested frames in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to handle this nested `iframe` with Selenium Web Driver?:

[image]

Comment: There is a image so please click on the question  "How to handle this nested frames in selenium webDriver?"....

Comment: What code base are you using?

Comment: Also, the code you're attempting to switch frames on would be very helpful as would anything you've already tried with no success

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-webdriver

Comment: Can you share your code trials and the text formatted `HTML` for analysis?

Comment: I found an answer. Thank you all for responding.