# Difficulties with Webdriver switching its focus to an iframe

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am having difficulties with webdriver switching its focus to an iframe
I have tried all standard webdriver commands including below without much luck ... i really appreciate if some one could help with this ?

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
```

Here is my html code:

```
<iframe class="x-component x-fit-item x-component-default" frameborder="0" src="/portal/page?libraryContext=7934fbba34c3d5bb965bcc33ff3a45acef04ff13d6e700ed7cc64a926f62db8e&amp;siteId=LT1&amp;menu=wm.config#wm.config.warehouse.warehouse////" name="1stPage:wm.config.warehouse.warehouse;Menu:wm.config;Ctx:7934fbba34c3d5bb965bcc33ff3a45acef04ff13d6e700ed7cc64a926f62db8e-1515619700794" data-lifecycle-participant="true" id="jdaIFrame-1026" style="margin: 0px; width: 1319px; height: 924px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: what do you mean by difficulties? what is the issue?

Comment: What's wrong with using the ID or any number of other attributes? Or you can switch by index. Have you tried any of these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle iframe in Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: webdriver is returning no element found exception when i tried id or name or index ... it works now by using below xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the `HTML` you have provided you can use the following line of code to switch to the `iframe` :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='x-component x-fit-item x-component-default' and starts-with(@id,'jdaIFrame-') and contains(@src,'/portal/page?libraryContext=')]")));
```