# XPath failing to select element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Can someone give a better xpath of this div element, or help explain why I cannot seem to select the desired div?

This XPath does not work:

```
//div[starts-with(normalize-space(.),'Welcome to the Shipt Shopper') and @class='text']
```

Even though it gets highlighted in chrome developer tool, NoSuchElementException is thrown.

This is the case with all elements on the page

A snippet of the HTML from the page with the content that I am trying to target:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content" style="padding-top: 116px;">                               
        <div class="media">         
          <div class="attachment" data-attachment="{&quot;image&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/images.typeform.com\/images\/29rsVwT3VF\/image\/default#.png&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:360,&quot;height&quot;:137,&quot;video_source&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;video_id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" style="width: 360px; height: 137px;">
<img src="https://images.typeform.com/images/29rsVwT3VF/image/default#.png" data-original="https://images.typeform.com/images/29rsVwT3VF/image/default#.png" style="width: 360px; height: 137px; display: inline;">
  </div>
</div>                      
        <div class="text" style="padding-top: 30px; margin-left: 0px;">
                                                    Welcome to the Shipt Shopper application! <br><br>Ready to get started?

        </div>
        <div class="button-wrapper" style="margin-top: 30px;">
          <div class="button general full enabled hover-effect" style="">Begin</div>
        <div class="button-text">press <strong>ENTER</strong></div>
      </div>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the element dynamically injected?

Comment: the html is seen in the image

Comment: ...Yes, I'm asking if that section of HTML injected into the DOM by some external event, like a button click or popup.

Comment: no its not dynamically injected

Comment: If would be helpful if you posted the snippet of HTML, not just a screenshot from the developer tool. For instance, we could more easily determine whether the quotes part of the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle iframe in Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: @SharonJones You will need to wait for the iframe to complete loading. Use the frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(String frameLocator) expected condition  which will switch to the iframe automatically. Then use the query to find the welcome text. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

The content that you are targeting is inside of an `<iframe>`.

I'm not familiar with how to configure Selenium, but it looks as if you may need to switch to that frame. Since it does not have an `@id` you may need to select by position:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
```

and then execute the XPath.

When you are done, jump back to the containing HTML page:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: didnt help... same NoSuchElementException

Comment: Your XPath looks good, I think the problem is due to iframes. Either need to switch context and/or as @Grasshopper suggests, wait until it has loaded.

Comment: didnt realise its a frame. let me try switching to frame

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the `xpath` which you have used is a valid one and is correct. But **NoSuchElementException** will be thrown when you will try to interact with it through *Selenium*.

To interact with the element through *Selenium* you can use the following `xpath` :

```
//div[@class='content-wrapper']/div[@class='content']//div[@class='text' and contains(normalize-space(), 'Welcome to the Shipt Shopper application')]
```

But looking at the *HTML* it seems your have to induce `WebDriverWait` for the element to be visible as follows :

```
WebElement welcomeShiptShopper = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-wrapper']/div[@class='content']//div[@class='text' and contains(normalize-space(), 'Welcome to the Shipt Shopper application')]")));
```

The *webpage* doesn't opens at my end. As other's have indicated, the *WebElement* might be within `<iframe>` tag, in that case you have to switch to the appropiate *iframe* first using either of the following methods first :

- Switch through **`Frame Name`**

  ```
  driver.switchTo().frame("frame_name");
  ```
- Switch through **`Frame ID`**

  ```
  driver.switchTo().frame("frame_id");
  ```
- Switch through **`Frame Index`**

  ```
  driver.switchTo().frame(1);
  ```

Once you switch to the appropiate frame, now you can lookout for the *WebElement* with the suggested `xpaths` mentioned above.