# How to identify the element with text as Sign in with Google through xpath in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am performing Automation for a redbus application but I am finding the web elements using firebug and it will highlight the firefox browser but it doesn't work in a chrome browser.

Please review the following screenshots:
[Redbus website link](https://www.redbus.in/)

- step 1 Open redbus application URL =https://www.redbus.in/
- step 2 Click Accounts module
- step 3 Click sign or signup link

My XPath is :

```
.//*[@id='g-signin2']//span[text()='Sign in with Google']
```

[Chrome browser screenshot: Can not identify the webElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3oCd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle iframe in Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Google sign up link is in Iframe , in order to interact with elements which are inside the frame/iframe , you need to change the focus of your web driver to that particular frame.

How you can do that in your case :

```
driver.switchTo.frame("//iframe[@class='modalIframe']")
```

Then you can interact with **Sign in with Google**.

```
WebElement signupButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'signed') and text()='Sign in with Google']")))  
signupButton.click();
```

HTH !

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id //iframe[@class='modalIframe']
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:884)
 at testdemo.sapmletest.main(sapmletest.java:34)

Comment: Use this Xpath for switching the focus :  driver.switchTo.frame("//div[@class='modal']/descendant::iframe") , you might wanna use explicit wait too before switching , let me know for any further assistance.

Comment: you can try with this code also : new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal']/descendant::iframe")));

Answer (score 0):

To *identify* and invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Sign in with Google**, as the element is within an . So you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for both the cases, once for the *frame to be available* and again for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='modalIframe' and @src='/account?pageName=Home&noReload=noReload']")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='abcRioButtonContents']//span[normalize-space()='Sign in with Google']"))).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks the login popup is available inside the iframe tag. First navigate to that particular frame as below and then add the sign in xpath step.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Comment: This will not work because there are more than one `IFRAME` on the page and the OP wants is not the first one.

Answer (score -1):

What You have here is modal frame, You should first switch on it, and the do actions on elements:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("modalIframe");
```

or maybe this:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement()
```

Comment: This will not work because the name of the `IFRAME` is not `modalIframe`... that's the `class`.