# building xpath with #document tag in html

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I build the xpath for `Try it` button from this website:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='iframewrapper']/iframe/????")).click();`

Also I tried this xpath `//body[@contenteditable='false']/button` which I know that isn't recommended. In Chrome `console` apear ok, but in Selenium doesn't find it and I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle iframe in Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write this code, First you need to switch to Frame and then you need to click that button

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult")    
driver.findElement(xpath: "//button[text()='Try it']").click()
```

Comment: It works with: `driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Try it']")).click();` Thank you !

Comment: Also I don't understand why I need to use switchTo() method before click() method

Comment: @BOB Iframe is equal to HTML within another HTML so it has its own scope so whenever you find your element is in Iframe you need to switch to that Iframe before you locate any element.

Comment: @Rajagopalan for completion purposes, is it necessary afterwards to "switch back" (assuming that we are still in the same page and we want now to get an element outside of the frame)? And if so, how to do that?

Comment: @khawabonga I did not understand your question , better you post another question.

Comment: @Rajagopalan let me give here the answer to my question, so it may help someone else: if after working with elements inside the frame, one needs to do something with elements outside the frame, one can do `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Comment: @khawabonga oh yes, you have to switch back. I confused because you used the word "outside"

Answer (score 4):

In case if you want to use WebDriverWait :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("iframeResult")));  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Try it') and @onclick='myFunction()']"))).click();
```

Comment: @Rajagopalan : Well , there is no harm if we use it.  Execution time would remain same.

Comment: Execution time doesn't remain same because you are checking whether element is enabled before you click! Checking for whether element is enabled takes time.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : That's hardly 500ms , even less if element is found immediately. Plus you will have stability.

Comment: Yes, but I want to tell you execution time doesn't remain same! I agree that's negligible.

Comment: @Rajagopalan No, the execution time *does* remain exactly the same. If a wait is not necessary, then the initial check that the wait does will succeed... thus the execution time is exactly the same. If it's not exactly the same, then the wait had to wait and the find without a wait will fail. Adding a wait adds no time to the execution time if the element is already present.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Further more, if the page ever does need a brief pause because it loads slowly, this method is safe where no wait will fail. This will avoid unnecessary intermittent failures.