# Selenium test fails on assert element exists, but it does exist

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver

I ran Selenium test and it fails on step #5, step #5 states:

`assert element present: xpath=(//span[text()='France'])`

But there is `<span>` element on the page and it contains "France" as it's content/text.

When I click on "Find target in page" (img #1) it actually highlights the element on the page, but for some reason the test case fails when I run it.

What could be the cause ?

img #1 ("Find target in page" button):

[image]

I'm using Selenium version 3.2.5 and firefox-dist-de-60.1.0.ESR-windows.

HTML part related to the span element looks like this:

`<span id="application_label">Deutsch</span>`

Comment: Please share html

Comment: @sers added HTML snippet.

Comment: Html code not look like it's element from screenshot. Share all block html, your code and error you get

Comment: @sers The screenshot is the button from Selenium, which, when you click on, will highlight the element on the web page if it exists.

Comment: Can’t help you without detailed information

Comment: @prsvr , Selenium has no buttons. Clarify the problem in more details as for now the question is unclear

Comment: @Andersson I'm using Firefox extension. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if element is not inside an iframe. If so, use switchTo().
   [How to handle iframe in Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)
2. Page could not be loaded yet, so selenium could not detect this element. Try to use Thread.sleep(10000) just to make sure it loaded completely and then put assertion.
   Hope it helps!