# Unable to locate element with href link

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn18c.png)

I am unable to locate the element having anchor tag with href link(Monthly link in loser tab - check attached image). Getting NoSuchElementFound exception. Already tried using javascript executor and waits .

**HTML :**

```
<div style="width:50%;font-size:14px;float:right;">
    <h2 class="f16 bold">Losers</h2>    
    <div class="tabs">
<a href="//money.rediff.com/losers/bse/daily">Daily</a>
</div>
    <div class="tabs">
<a href="//money.rediff.com/losers/bse/weekly">Weekly</a>
</div>
    <div class="tabs">
<a href="//money.rediff.com/losers/bse/monthly">Monthly</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: ...and post the code you have tried. Add a tag for the relevant programming language also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle iframe in Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding the component using xpath. Try the code below. This might help you

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'leftcontainer')]/div[3]/div[3]/a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element **Losers -> Monthly** as the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following *Python* based solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://money.rediff.com/losers/bse/monthly")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='logwatch']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(., 'Losers')]//following::div[@class='curLink tabs']/a[contains(., 'Monthly')]"))).click()
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in selenium for this case, is to use linkText (org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText) which you pass the text inside the a tag, and will return the equals match. For proper usage, you can use chain also, here is a simple example:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.ByChained;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import static org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText;
import static org.openqa.selenium.By.cssSelector;

public static By chain(final By... bys) {
        return new ByChained(bys);
    }

public void yourClickMethodOnAElements(final String name) {
        click(chain(cssSelector("div.tabs > a"), linkText(name)));
    }
public WebElement click(final By by) {
        return click(driver.findElement(by));
    }

public WebElement click(WebElement element) {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
        sleepIfNeeded();
        return element;
    }
```

This is a simplified version, you can improve it with waiters checks etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple xpath example for `<a href="foo">`

```
"//a[contains(@href,'foo')]"
```