# I'm getting empty string for tinymce

Tags: java, selenium, tinymce

I'm working on selenium and I have to automate tinyMCE in my web page.
I tried many ways but always get `null` for code below:

```
(String)js.executeScript("tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().isContentEditable");
```

Comment: What do you get executing in browser console?

Comment: In the eclipse console, i'm getting this.
Running JavaScript 'tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().isContentEditable' with parameters '[]'

Comment: in the browser console I'm getting correct value as false. Because it is in readonly state.

Comment: if editor is inside iframe element switch to it. [How to switch to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: unfortunately there is no iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return` to the front of your JS script, e.g.

```
(String)js.executeScript("return tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().isContentEditable");
```