# Selenium can't find 99% of elements, why?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium with Python and Firefox on Windows 7. 
Running through my script, at some point Selenium can't find any elements beside  and  after I navigated to a certain part of a website.
The website belongs to an E-Mail provider called freemail (https://web.de/). I have set up a test account to complete a training project from chapter 11 of the book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python".

Python, Selenium and Firefox are all up to date. And before this certain part of the website everything was working fine (including finding tags, class names, id's etc.).
I tried like 10 different ways to click one of the ways to navigate to the inbox of the E-Mail provider but had no luck in making it work.

Here is the **[HTMLcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwBpk.jpg)** with the highlighted element I want Selenium to click.
Here another image of the **[Website itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl9Gv.jpg)** with the button highlighted in the upper left corner.

**And this is the code for my script:**

```
## This program navigates through the website of an
## e-mail provider and sends a mail automatically.

# Import necessary modules
from selenium import webdriver
# Mail account info
mailLink = 'https://web.de/'
mailAddress = 'testing2772@web.de'    # This is just a test account
mailPw = 'ewaa11ewaa11'

# Recipient % content of the e-mail
recipient = 'pradicradr@matra.top'
mailContent = 'Test this awesome string.'

# Set up browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(mailLink)

# Log into account
browser.find_element_by_class_name('icon-freemail').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('freemailLoginUsername').send_keys(mailAddress)
pwElem = browser.find_element_by_id('freemailLoginPassword')
pwElem.send_keys(mailPw)
pwElem.submit()

# Close notification overlay if it pops up
try:
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('layerCloser').click()
except:
    pass


## At this point Selenium can't Find 99% of elements including the one I need

## Testing if Selenium finds basic elements
testElem1 = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')   # works
testElem2 = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')   # works
testElem3 = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('div')   # works

## Click link to inbox (all of these variants won't work somehow)
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_class_name('nx-track-sec-click-communication-newmail')   # try by class_name
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a")   # try by XPath
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_link_text('E-Mail schreiben')   # try by link_text
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.nx-track-sec-click-communication-newmail')   # try by CSS selector
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.newmail')   # try by CSS selector
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.nx-track nx-track-sec-click-communication-newmail newmail')   # another try by CSS selector
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="E-Mail schreiben"]')   # another try by CSS selector

## TODO: Click link to write a new mail
## TODO: Fill in recipient and mail content
## TODO: Send mail and close program
```

I guess it has something to do with an iframe? But I'm a beginner and I don't know how to handle this :/

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:**
I solved the problem by finding another button that linked to the inbox with 
`browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/atlas-app/atl-navbar/atl-actions-menu/div[1]/div[1]/atl-menu-item[2]/pos-icon-item/span/span").click()`. This button is not within an iframe, so no problem here.

However, it is still strange that I can't enter any iframes. Here is another **[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byg8H.jpg)** to make it more clear. **Does anybody know how to switch to that iframe?**
`browser.switch_to.default_content()` and then `browser.switch_to.frame('home')` doesn't do the trick...

---

**SECOND EDIT:**
KunduK's answer did it. 
The problem was, that the script needs to wait for the iframe to become available and then for the button to become available after that. See his post further down for the exact approach. **Thanks everyone!**

Comment: your missing a `-` in `'nx-track-sec-click communication-newmail'`

Comment: change it to `nx-track nx-track-sec-click-communication-newmail newmail`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I included the "-" (I failed to copy it properly) and tried all three classes, but there is still the error:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .nx-track nx-track-sec-click-communication-newmail newmail

Comment: option 2 is more of a css selector hack, hopefully the website only has 1 anchor link with the title "E-Mail schreiben"

Comment: Check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java (Java is involved, but Selenium syntax is pretty much the same).

Comment: Yeah, it seems to have to do with switching iframes. See Corey Goldberg's answer for following this further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the `E-Mail schreiben` link you need to switched to `iframe` first and then click on link.Use `WebDriverWait` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` and then use `element_to_be_clickable`

```
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,'home')))
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="navigation"]//ul//li[@class="item"]//a[@title="E-Mail schreiben"]'))).click()
```

You need to use following imports to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

> I guess it has something to do with an iframe?

Since the elements you are trying to find are in an iframe, you must first switch to the iframe before finding the elements. Your iframe has a `name=home` attribute, so you should be able to add:

`driver.switch_to.frame('home')`

... then find the elements.

Once you are done interacting with the iframe and want to switch back to the top level content, use:

`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: To make sure I start within the original content, I followed the line     `browser.switch_to.default_content()`     with     `browser.switch_to.frame('home')`     and started another try with     `browser.switch_to.frame('thirdPartyFrame_home')`.     But both times an exception was raised that declared:     `NoSuchFrameException(frame_reference)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: home`     or     `raise NoSuchFrameException(frame_reference)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: thirdPartyFrame_home`

Comment: I edited my original question, to make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

```
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.nx-track.nx-track-sec-click-communication-newmail.newmail')   # try by CSS selector
```

#### Option 2

use the title property of the anchor link

```
linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="E-Mail schreiben"]')
```

#### option 3

re-read the docs: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Doesn't work sadly... The error output still persists:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: a.nx-track nx-track-sec-click-communication-newmail newmail

Comment: there is a few `.` missing from that

Comment: did you try the second version?

Comment: @Magnesia please let me know how it goes

Comment: :D I'm testing it right now (Thanks again!) I edit the lines of code in my question as I go. The option "linkToInbox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="E-Mail schreiben"]')" doesn't seem to work either: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: a[title="E-Mail schreiben"]"

Comment: try dumping the html from selenium then compare it against your browser version. it might not loading everything properly ```body_html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
print(body_html.text)```

Comment: @Magnesia - I think scroll is required to load all elements ?

Comment: doubt that @AmitJain

Comment: @Amit Jain - Scrolling is not the problem :)

Comment: I edited my original question, to make the problem more clear.