# Build xpath with iFrame from jqueryui.com

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, iframe

I am on the https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ website where I am trying to build xpath for the first selector `Select a speed`. I build the xpath to iframe but how to reach the first selector `Select a speed`?

```
//body/div[@id='container']/div[@id='content-wrapper']/div[1]/div[1]/iframe[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your elements are inside the `iframe` in order to access these elements you should first switch to the `iframe` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)
Also, to locate the `iframe` you can simply use one of the following `xpath`s`//iframe` or `//iframe[@class='demo-frame']` or select by class `demo-frame` etc.
After switching into the `ifame` the `xpath` to select a speed is `//span[@id='speed-button']`

Comment: I didn't get what it means `After switching into the ifame`. Can I build one xpath directly to @id='speed-button'?