# how can i verify text under iframe tag

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

[Iframe want to verify text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2etW.png)

there is a link: Xbshhdss that click it open a iframe and under the iframe there is only a Scripts tag which comes the api frome the other functionality

it is a form that that is to be filled and i want to verify text in the form ho can i please refer image link

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942928/how-to-handle-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Steps to use Frame elements:

1. Identify the frame by id or name
2. Switch to the frame
3. find your element.